# Flink Scala API - apply new WindowFunction vs apply function

Tags: scala, apache-flink

I modified the basic wordcount example of Flink and played with window functions.

The apply method of WindowedStream is overloaded and it accepts a function:

```
def apply[R: TypeInformation](
    function: (K, W, Iterable[T], Collector[R]) => Unit): DataStream[R] = { ... }
```

as well as WindowFunction:

```
def apply[R: TypeInformation](
    function: WindowFunction[T, R, K, W]): DataStream[R] = { ... }
```

I get my code to compile when giving a function to the apply method on the WindowedStream, but my code does not compile with my WindowFunction (and I don't know why ..).

This is the basic stream:

```
val windowCounts: WindowedStream[WordWithCount, String, TimeWindow] = text
    .flatMap { w => w.split("\\s") }
    .map { w => WordWithCount(w, 1) }
    .keyBy(t => "all")
    .window(SlidingProcessingTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(30), Time.seconds(10)))
```

And this are my implenmentations of the window function.
This one works for me:

```
def distinctCount(
    s: String, tw: TimeWindow, input: Iterable[WordWithCount],
    out: Collector[String]): Unit = {
  val discount = input.map(t => t.word).toSet.size
  out.collect(s"Distinct elements: $discount")
}

// compiles
val distinctCountStream = windowCounts.apply { distinctCount _ }
```

This one doesn't compile:

```
class DiscountWindowFunction extends WindowFunction[WordWithCount, String, String, TimeWindow] {
  override def apply(key: String, window: TimeWindow, input: lang.Iterable[WordWithCount], out: Collector[String]): Unit = {
    val discount = input.map(t => t.word).toSet.size
    out.collect(s"Distinct elements: $discount")
  }
  def apply(key: String, window: TimeWindow, input: Iterable[(String, Int)], out: Collector[String]): Unit = {
    apply(key, window, input.asJava, out)
  }
}

// does not compile
val distinctCount = windowCounts.apply(new DiscountWindowFunction())
```

I'm using Flink 1.3.2 and this are my imports:

```
import java.lang
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.windowing.WindowFunction
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala._
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.windowing.assigners.SlidingProcessingTimeWindows
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.windowing.time.Time
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.windowing.windows.TimeWindow
import org.apache.flink.util.Collector
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have imported the `WindowFunction` that is used in the Java DataStream API.

Your code should compile when you replace

```
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.windowing.WindowFunction
```

by

```
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala.function.WindowFunction
```

Btw. thanks for the complete information :-)

Comment: Oh yes, thank you! Changing the import is the solution. It didn't occur to me that there might be a `WindowFunction.scala`.